# removeFromSuperview() Not Removing Reference To View, CPU Load Remains High

Tags: ios, swift

I have an activity indicator that I created. It's a series of five `UIViews` that animate their alphas from 0.0 -> 1.0 for about 3 seconds a piece. In the device profile the CPU is over 100% and energy usage is "Very High". The profile levels remain at that height even after running `.removeFromSuperview()` on the container view of the activityIndicator, also the same if I remove each subview from the container view and then the container itself.

My question is what is the proper way to remove a series of views from a parent view so they no longer are referenced? Or I suppose that I could be asking the wrong question, maybe it's not in the removal but in the implementation of the activity view. Why would that type of simple animation create such a high CPU load?

The high load happens most specifically when the activityIndicator is placed in a `viewController` over a nested `tableView` while the tableView loads.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    if currentMatchObject == nil {

        let indicator = SquaresActivityIndicator()

        checkForUser(self) { () -> () in

            delay(2.0, closure: { () -> () in

                indicator.stopIndicator(self.view)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    self.matchTableView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
                    self.matchTableView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height * 0.75
                    self.matchTableView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height * 0.10
                    self.matchTableView.frame.origin.x = centerXAlignment(self.matchTableView, masterView: self.view)
                    self.matchTableView.backgroundColor = bgColor

                })

            })

            self.reloadMatchView()
        }

        indicator.runIndicator(self.view, percentageSize: 15.0, activityBorderWidth: 6.0)

    } else {

        self.reloadMatchView()

    }


}
```

ActivityIndicator stop function:

```
func stopIndicator(masterView: UIView) {

    let viewToRemove = masterView.viewWithTag(123)

    for v in (viewToRemove?.subviews)! {

        v.removeFromSuperview()

    }

    viewToRemove?.removeFromSuperview()


}
```

[image]

Comment: It would help to show your relevant code.

Comment: Where does Instruments indicate you're spending your time? The Time Profiler in Instruments should be your first stop when CPU assessing performance problems. Absent that, I'd strongly suspect both problems are in `runIndicator`.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure on the Instruments question. I have yet to dig heavily into it's functionality, unfortunately. I've only made a couple of runs in Instrument and it reading 98%+ on the main thread. `runIndicator` is a heavy function. It contains all of the animation of the indicator. So I would agree that something in there is causing the load but is all of that function not removed when I call `removeFromSuperview()` on the views that it's working on?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this problem with animations or iterations in another threads.

#### How detect code?

> Attention: as example i use my application.

1. Run instruments and choose **Time**

[image: Choose Time Profiling]

2. Start application and "go to" high load processor. Wait few seconds for aggregate information. The next, find own method ;)

[image: Find own method]

And, code in this method:

```
- (void)animateKeep
{
    CGFloat angle = self.activeAngle;

    if (self.turnToLeft) {
        angle += 90;
    } else {
        angle -= 90;
    }

    self.activeAngle = angle;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:self.angleSpeed * 3 delay:.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(angle));
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self animateKeep];
    }];
}
```

And we see loop animation in completion code `[self animateKeep]`. And we should control all animation and stop animation before remove from superview.

Solution in this example - add custom flag (bool) and in start method control this flag.

#### Solution:

You should stop all animations and iterations (if exist in another thread) for this view before remove from superview.